# Creating new user in Dynamics GP

Tags: dynamics-gp

I have created new user 'testUser' in Dynamics GP company lets say 'TWO', there is another database on same server which is a non GP company database lets say 'TEST'. There are few tables in TEST db which I need to read on my some Dynamics GP form. I have created a view in database 'TWO' to read records from this table.

```
create view TestView 
as 
select description from TEST..table1
GO
```

But when accessing this view in GP form I am getting permission error for my user testUser.
I went to SQL server and mark database 'TEST' for user testUser.
After that I get select permission message on view TestView.
after running

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on TestView to testUser.
```

I got no more issues. But is there any query by using which I will give permission to users whenever new user will be created in Dynamics GP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should grant the permissions to the DYNGRP role on the database.

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on TestView to DYNGRP.
```

This should give all gp Users those permissions. Any User created afterward will have those permissions.